# Docker does not update volume when updating .sql file

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, devops

I have a docker compose file that looks like this

```
version: '3'
services:
  webapp:
    build: '.'
    ports: 
      - "8000:8000"
    networks:
      - db

  postgres:
    image: "postgres:alpine"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "password"
    volumes:
      - "./scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
    networks:
      - db
networks: 
  db:
```

The **scripts** folder looks like this:

```
|- scripts
 |-- init.sh
 |-- init.sql
```

**The Problem**

My workflow for this project is progressive, so I add some SQL initialization data on my host OS, run `sudo docker-compose down -v` and then `sudo docker-compose up`. I did not update my user to not need the use of sudo for this scenario.

When I update the `init.sh` file, then these updates are reflected each time I run `docker-compose up`. The `init.sql` file however, only remembers the first "version" of this file. Any subsequent updates are ignored when running `docker-compose up`.

**Things I tried**

- Tried `sudo docker-compose up --renew-anon-volumes --force-recreate` which also does not seem to help.
- Tried pruning all the volumes with `sudo docker volume prune`. Does not help
- Tried pruning the docker system with `sudo docker system prune`
- What does work is if I copy the file and it's content to a new file name. **Renaming the file does not work**

So the question is simply, how do I get content updates of `init.sql` to be recognized by my docker compose setup?? I don't understand why changes to `init.sh` is picked up but changes to `init.sql` are ignored?

**UPDATE**

One important piece of information is that the project is sitting on a virtualbox shared folder, so the underlying file system is `vboxsf` while all of this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the underlying file system is playing a role here **when using Docker Volumes**. I have been using a virtualbox vm and the project was sitting on a `vboxsf` file system. So when attaching a volume in my `docker compose` scenario(?), it has been attaching to a `vboxsf` volume this whole time.

When I moved the project from the `vboxsf` filesystem to something else (whatever my home directory filesystem has, `ext4` I think) then updates to the files worked as expected.

-----------*I speak under correction here, link is important to track*--------------

My understanding is that the way vboxsf works is that changes are broadcasted between host and guest filesystems and this is picked up by the host and guest OS. There is also an aspect about how shared memory is accessed, but I really don't have that kind of knowledge to elaborate on it further.

To understand the issue, this link seems to be the best resource for now:
https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/819?cversion=0&cnum_hist=70

-------------------*End*----------------------------------

I don't think that this will be a problem in production, but it will definitely make you question your sanity for local development.

**So please, when you are using a Linux VM for development, check which filesystem your Docker Volumes are using before you even start working on a project.**

**There is no error messages at all, which is the one of the worst circumstances to be in when debugging this problem!!**

**I also wasted about 2 days worth of life trying to figure out what's going on and how to fix it. Hopefully this 2 wasted days can result in many days saved instead :D**